# Multiple font types in a QML Text

Tags: qt, qml

I need to write a text using multiple font types. I tried to do it by using rich text like this:

```
Text{
    id: test
    textFormat: Text.RichText
    color: "#297fca"
    text: "<span style = 'font-family: Roboto Medium; font-size: 15px'>Text in on font.</span> And in another"
    anchors{
        top: description.bottom
        topMargin: 40
        left: headDesign.right
        leftMargin: 75
    }
}
```

The text whose font I want to change becomes larger but the font is not loaded. Roboto Medium is a font that I loaded using a font loader.

So, any Ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried [FontLoader](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-fontloader.html)

Comment: Both fonts are loaded using font loader. Sorry if I was not clear. I meant tha the font does not show up in what in the message. It is all the default font

Comment: `RichText` does not implement the full HTML spec.  Perhaps the font- family inside style isn't implemented.  You can set the font like `Text { text: "Fixed-size font"; font.family: fixedFont.name }`, where `fixedFont` is the id of the `FontLoader` element.

Comment: Problem with this approach is that when you do this, you need to create a completely new Text field for the other font. This is not at all a good solution when your text is a paragraph and the font change is in the midlle of the paragraph

Comment: Can you please post the code you use to load the font? The `font-family` is a supported CSS property and should work. Your code works well for me when I try with another font, so I believe there is a problem with your loader. See [Supported HTML Subset](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html). Note that you can also use the `font` tag: `text: "<font face='Roboto Medium' size='15'>Text in on font.</font> And in another"`

Comment: When I get back home, I see if I can post the code

Answer (score 2):

Please check did the font load correctly.

```
FontLoader {
    source: "riesling.ttf"
    Component.onCompleted: console.log(name)
}

Text{
    id: test
    textFormat: Text.RichText
    color: "#297fca"
    text: "<div style = 'font-family: Riesling; font-size: 25px'>Same Text.</div>
           <div style = 'font-size: 25px'>Same Text.</div>"
}
```

Font: https://www.1001freefonts.com/

Made them display separate line to see the difference clearly.

**Qt 5.10.1 result**

[image]